# getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher doesn't forward to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, servlets

I'm working on a page that displays a database's information on a dashboard when an user succesfully logs in. It has other buttons on the aside section that display this information too. The problem is that after the login the information doesn't get displayed on dashboard.jsp using getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher to send it said information but does get displayed using one of the buttons that accesses the servlet directly.

usersServlet code

```
@WebServlet(name = "usersServlet",value = "users")
public class UsersServlet extends HttpServlet {

    UserService userService;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
        userService = new UserServiceImpl((Connection) request.getAttribute("conn"));
        List<User> users = userService.listUsers();
        request.setAttribute("users",users);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/users/list.jsp").forward(request,response);

    }
```

dashboard.jsp which builds the page. list.jsp is accessed correctly up and shows its content up until the user information.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<jsp:include page="layout/header.jsp"/>
<jsp:include page="layout/content.jsp"/>

<!-- Contenido de la página -->
<h1>Este es el Home</h1>
<jsp:include page="users/list.jsp"/>
<jsp:include page="layout/footer.jsp"/>
```

list.jsp which is supposed to show the the users on the dashboard but only shows the column's names. Works when accesing the servlet directly

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!-- Contenido de la página -->
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 15px">
    <script>
        console.log("Número de usuarios: ${users.size()}");

        <c:forEach var="usuario" items="${users}">
        console.log("Usuario: ${usuario.name}");
        </c:forEach>
    </script>

    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4" style="width: 100px;" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/users/NewUser.jsp">Nuevo</a>  <!-- OJO ACA-->
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th scope="col">Código</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Correo</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${users}" var="usuario">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"
                       style="padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;">
                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt me-2" style="margin-right: 0px !important;"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"
                       style="padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt me-2" style="margin-right: 0px !important;"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>${usuario.id}</td>
                <td>${usuario.name}</td>
                <td>${usuario.username}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<jsp:include page="../layout/footer.jsp"/>
```

All other servlets related to retrieving the information show it correctly and work without issues. I added pieces of code to both list.jsp and usersServlet to verify it and they did display the information, but only after accesing the part of the page that accesses usersServlet by value. Here's my web.xml. Keep in mind that it was not mentioned in class that we should change it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">
</web-app>
```